# I can't scroll vertically in a webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

In my android app I have a webview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that I can't scroll the page vertically. Horizontally it works pretty well but not vertically. Now if I set the size of android:layout_height to 400dp for example then it works! but then I can't support multiple screen sizes... any idea?

Comment: Why don't you set the WebView to `fill_parent` ?

Comment: Well, I am using a RelativeLayout because I need other elements beside the WebView, but a proper LinearLayout(i.e with orientation set, as in Roman Black's answer) should also work; maybe it's a problem with your Java code? or with the HTML page you are trying to open? Try to add some more code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

or

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to LinearLayout

Comment: it doesn't work because LinearLayout is not scrollable layout. When you set height and width to wrap_content the borders of webview are out of borders of LinearLayout. When you set orientation to layout also set webview height and width to fill_parent.

Comment: so what would you recommend to do what I want ?

Comment: ok I got it working, there was a strange disallowintercept thing that was conflicting with that view

Comment: @Jafar Can you elaborate on how you fixed it?

Comment: It's an old app that was made for android 2.x. At this time TabActivity wasn't deprecated and the app makes use of it (it's not recommended to use it anymore). The layout of a TabActivity is composed by a TabWidget and a TabHost. The TabHost was customized in a strange way with an entanglement of ScrollView and LinearLayout. Those were customized as well (some event listeners for scrolling were overridden). I just refactored that view to make it work. Generally it's not a good idea to make scrollable containers nested. If you have more problems just post your code, I'll be pleased to help you!

Answer (score 2):

To me it worked by enabling the javascript on the webview. So I guess there is some issue with webkit rendering a page that contains javascript if that flag is not set.

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Good to point it out.. In my case, enabling JavaScript caused the scroll getting stuck issue. But disabling it renders the page useless too :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put the webview in a scroll view, by increasing the height to 400 dp you are putting it outside the limitations of the linear layout which creates a scroll view. when the page is loaded the linear layout doesn't take this into account.

Comment: I tried to replace the linear layout by a scroll view -> didn't work. I also tried to surround the linear layout (containing the webview) by  a scroll view but it didn't work either. How would you do that?